# Convert HTTP Path to UNC Path?

Tags: api, unc

I'm working with an API that requires a UNC path to a file in order to utilize it, but in my case my file is hosted remotely.

Let's say my file is hosted at http://example.com/file.pdf

I may be misunderstanding how this would work, but what is the correctly formatted path to provide to the api if it is looking for a UNC path?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to retrieve the file first and place its contents someplace within the namespace of UNC paths. Web servers are not in the namespace of UNC paths.

Comment: Thanks! Will follow up with the API devs to see if there is a way around this.